# Need serious assembly help

Tags: assembly

I have been trying to learn assembly for a few years now. I get to do a "Hello, World" program but never further. I find it so hard. Is anyone able to point me to a place or maybe even themselves, teach me some? I have prior programming experice mainly in python. So i am not completely unfamiliar with programming.

Comment: I learned some Motorola assembly and I don't think the language itself is hard, more like the concepts were so foreign that I made it seem harder than it was.

Comment: Assembly for which processor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overwhelmed while learning assembly. Orientation please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129028/overwhelmed-while-learning-assembly-orientation-please)

Comment: ... and for what Operating System?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208983/assembly-language-can-anyone-recommend-good-introductory-resources-closed

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199679/whats-the-best-beginner-book-for-assembly-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe start with comparing it to python, since that is what you are familar with.
This [link](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Comparison_and_Review/) brings you to a site that compares programming languages. If you go to "99 Bottles of Beer" it shows the program in multiple languages which allows you to compare the python one with the assembler one to make links that can help you later. Other than that I would recommend looking up examples of simple programs to start off with and then going through them and making changes so you understand why and how it works. Then after that they are sites that release programming challenge questions and that allows you to try out new programs that you wouldn't have otherwise thought to try.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this book with great success, starts from the beginning, and works through to more complex topics: [Assembly Language Step-by-Step](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Assembly-Language-Step-Step-Programming/dp/0471375233/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1275925183&sr=8-2)

Answer (score 1):

It is much faster to learn assembly language if you pair it with a debugger, it really did made me understand how values exchanges with registers, memory addresses, and how processors work under the hood, every step of the trace modifies the state of the system, i think that's one of the shortcuts to learning it, i suggest you choose the more graphical ones so you can easily visualize whats happening may it be 16, 32, or 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Start with learning C. From C to assembly language is a small step (maybe not so small, but a lot of statements can be translated 1-to-1), and probably you will find that you do not need assembly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some help in these popular questions:

[Learning assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360279/learning-assembly)

[Resources for learning ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/resources-for-learning-arm-assembly)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  It should also be accompanied by a close vote.